# Cannot use Swiper with "vue": "^2.6.11"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, swiper.js

I am trying to use Swiper with `"vue": "^2.6.11"`, but it throws runtime errors. I followed the guide from https://swiperjs.com/vue, and changed the imports to:

```js
// Import Swiper Vue.js components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue/swiper-vue.js';

// Import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css';
```

Error message:

> Property or method "onSwiper" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render, Invalid handler for event "swiper": got undefined , Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

Comment: What version of Swiper did you installed? Did you check that istalled version supports Vue 2? Why you changed the import ?

Comment: I try 6,7 and 8 version, but in all cases have errors. I change import because it can not find css files without direct route.

Comment: No i did not check which version support vue 2, where can I see that?

Comment: Can you show the remaining part of your code? Do you have anything in your template part? Did you add       const onSwiper = (swiper) => {
        console.log(swiper);
      }; ? I guess your template has @swiper attribute somewhere

Comment: if you use vue 2, better use this component: https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-awesome-swiper

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Swiper components only work with Vue 3](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/discussions/4759). Those components cannot be used in Vue 2, but the Swiper API can be used directly instead:

1. Apply a [template ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/?redirect=true#ref) on the target Swiper container element in the template.
2. In the component's [`mounted()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/?redirect=true#mounted) hook, [initialize an instance of `Swiper`](https://swiperjs.com/get-started#initialize-swiper), passing the template ref and Swiper options that include selectors for the pagination/navigation elements in the template.

```html
<script>
import Swiper, { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper'
import 'swiper/css'
import 'swiper/css/navigation'
import 'swiper/css/pagination'

export default {
  mounted() {
    2️⃣
    new Swiper(this.$refs.swiper, {
      // configure Swiper to use modules
      modules: [Navigation, Pagination],
      // Optional parameters
      loop: true,

      // If we need pagination
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
      },

      // Navigation arrows
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },

      // And if we need scrollbar
      scrollbar: {
        el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
      },
    })
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <!-- Slider main container -->
  <div 1️⃣ ref="swiper" class="swiper">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <!-- Slides -->
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
    <!-- If we need pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

    <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.swiper-slide {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
</style>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-swiper?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMySlides.vue)

Answer (score 4):

Make some additions for [@tony19'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71227131/6904888)s good answer.

Here is a demo example project: [Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-swiper-api?file=src/components/MySlides.vue)

```html
<script>
import Swiper, { Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay } from 'swiper'
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      activeIndex: 0,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const SECOND = 1000 // milliseconds

    new Swiper(this.$refs.swiper, {

      modules: [Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay],

      loop: true,
      autoplay: {
        delay: 3 * SECOND,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
      },
      speed: 2 * SECOND,
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },

      on: {
        slideChange: (swiper) => {
          this.activeIndex = swiper.realIndex
        },
      },
    })
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: The key difference for the `swiper@8.4.4` is to import whole bundle stylesheets.